# Is there a stop processing and exit command?

Tags: pug

Instead of nesting many if then/else blocks resulting in deep indents in a pug script, is there an option to stop further processing and simply exit?

I tried:

```
- return
```

but it returns a blank page.

Comment: I know It's been so long, But I need exactly this, Had you find any stuff then?

Comment: No. I am still hoping for something. I want to use it right away.

Comment: I've raised an issue on Github https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/3379, but it seems no one is active here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `break` or `continue` (although you need to prefix them with `-`) in `each` / `while` blocks:

```
each letter in "ABCDEFGHIJ"
  if letter === "E"
    - break
  h1= letter
```

Output:

```
<h1>A</h1>
<h1>B</h1>
<h1>C</h1>
<h1>D</h1>
```